# How long is valid MachineKey encrypted string or no expiry for that

Tags: c#, security, encryption, c#-4.0, machinekey

What will be the lifetime for encrypted string using machine key as below: 
//System.Web.Security

```
MachineKey.Protect(streamarray,purpose);


MachineKey.Unprotect(string,purpose);
```

How long protected string is valid. I could not find anywhere that mention, but I believe, its valid and no expiry, is it correct understanding ?

Comment: Generally data doesn't go out of date. Your key or the accompanying certificate may go out of date though. Or the machine itself may get destroyed one way or the other.

Comment: The data will remain decryptable for as long as the machine key remains the same. This key can be [changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649308(v=pandp.10)), or in more recent versions [overridden with a custom mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey), but it does not expire, nor does the data encrypted with it.

Comment: Ok. got it. So, I'll make machinekey within web.config file so, its remains unchanged. Thank You so much !.

Comment: I've another issue with existing setting that just found. If you can see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607115/how-to-do-machinekey-encryption-in-load-balancing . Thanks.