# How do I move a AutoGenerate,IsolateApps machine key system onto a load balanced server?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, c#-4.0, machinekey

I just found, web.config with below settings in all the environments including prod.

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1"
                    decryption="Auto" />
```

Now, application is going to start using with load balancing. Would it create problem as its not using static machine keys ?

If I change this key now to static validaitnKey and static decrptionKey then it creates another problem for already protected keys unable to decrypt.

```
MachineKey.Protect(streamarray,purpose);
MachineKey.Unprotect(string,purpose);
```

Can you please suggest, what can be done for existing protected keys and still, I can use load balancing.

Comment: I can not change the encryption method. Its already live and using `autoGenerate,Isolate` option and keys are already protected, But, it looks like, it will fail once load balancing start. so, how can I read the key so, it can be make same to other server web.config. Note. there need to support already protected keys to unprotect too.

Comment: How Can I read the key from `validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"` so, I can make similar key on other server.